# How can I update a total chart value in legendItemClick callback?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The title practically says it all. Here's an image with explanation of what I want.

[image: on series "show/"hide" I would like to update the "Chart total row below the chart (click for an image explanation)]

Here's a part of Highcharts config I use so far, but it calculates the sum incorrectly, because stackTotal property contains the whole Total, even of items that are hidden.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function(event) {
              // if visible, sum == 0, because this series will be hidden
              // if hidden, sum == total, because this series will be shown
              var sum = (this.visible ? this.data[0].stackTotal : 0),
                  index = this.index;
              $.each(this.chart.series, function(){
                if (this.visible && this.index != index) {
                    sum += this.data[0].stackTotal;
                }
              });
              $('.chart_total', '#doc_chart').text(sum);
            }
        }
    }
  },
```

How can I make it show a proper sum for the chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGurung/Mbrjx/8/) does what you are looking for.

When a `legendItem` is clicked, the handler starts with `chartTotal = 0`, then it loops through each series in the chart.

If the current series in the loop is **not the one that's clicked** (checked using `series.index`) then it computes the `seriesTotal` and adds it to the `chartTotal` **only if it's visible**.

Otherwise, if the current series is the **one that's clicked**, then it adds it's `seriesTotal` to the `chartTotal` **only if it's going to be visible** .

Finally, it updates the display with the value of `chartTotal`.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, ta muchly!

Comment: is this fiddle available somewhere else? current link gives 404... thanks.

Comment: @santuxus: The issue was that I had changed my user name there. Now that I reset it back to what it was, the link is working. Thanks for letting know.